# What is a better solution than brute force for this?

Tags: algorithm, performance, brute-force

Given a finite sequence of positive integers between [0-5]
lets say [0,3,1,5,2,4,4,4] and a starting sequence [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].
We now want to build our given sequence from the starting sequence by performing stepwise operations.
In one step, we can either increase all numbers from our starting sequence by 1 or increase just one index from this sequence by 1. 
Once we would increase a 5 in this case it would become a 0.

What is the most efficient way to find the solution that requires the least steps? This solution should of course also apply to other inputs (length + upper bound). For the starting sequence we can assume it is always 0 for each index.

The brute force approach could look like this.

```java
int upperBound = 5;
int[] endSequence = {0,3,1,5,2,4,4,4};
int currentBestSteps = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int currentTimesIncreaseAll = 0;

for(int start = 0;start <= upperBound;start++){ //how many times to increase all
  //counter how many steps required total, starting with start amount of steps
  //since we increase all values 'start' times  
  int counterSteps = start; 

  //go through all end values and calc how many steps required  
  for(int end:endSequence){ 
    if(start <= end){
      counterSteps += end-start;
    }else{
      counterSteps += end+upperBound+1-start;
    }
  }

  System.out.println("solution: increase all "+start+
                     " times, total steps: "+counterSteps);

  if(counterSteps < currentBestSteps){
    currentBestSteps = counterSteps;
    currentTimesIncreaseAll = start;
  }
}
System.out.println("best solution: increase all "+currentTimesIncreaseAll+
                   " times, total steps: "+currentBestSteps);
```

Results:

```java
solution: increase all 0 times, total steps: 23
solution: increase all 1 times, total steps: 22
solution: increase all 2 times, total steps: 21
solution: increase all 3 times, total steps: 20
solution: increase all 4 times, total steps: 19
solution: increase all 5 times, total steps: 30
best solution: increase all 4 times, total steps: 19
```

Comment: The best solution for the presented case would be to increase ALL indices 4 times, of course then you have to continue increasing every index != 4 seperately. So to get 3 for index 1 for example you need 5 steps. In total this would then be 19 steps.

Comment: I think you only have to test the number of increase-all as one of the unique values in the list, not all values from 0 to `upperBound`. Does not make a difference here, but might be significant if upperBound is a million and the array only has a few hundred elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to provide a way to decrement target original array (call it **A**) to make `[0,0,0,0...]`, either by decrementing everything or decrementing individual items.  This of course is the same question, but with the steps in reverse.

First, calculate the cost for decrementing all the elements one-by-one.  Call this cost **CMAX** and the length of the array **N**.  **CMAX = sum_for_all_i(A[i])**

Then sort the array, and find each position **i** where **i=0** or **A[i] > A[i-1]**.

For each such position it's easy to calculate the cost that would result from decrementing everything until **A[i]** reaches 0, and *then* decrementing one-by-one. It's easy, because we know that everything at index **< i** will wrap around, and everything with index **>= i** will not.  So:

**COST(i) = CMAX + A[i] - A[i] * (N-i) + i*(UPPER_BOUND+1-A[i])**

The **A[i]** is the cost of all the global decrements.  The **- A[i] * (N-i)** is the cost reduction for all the high elements that don't wrap around, and the cost **i*(UPPER_BOUND+1-A[i])** is the increased cost for all the elements that wrap around from **0** to **UPPER_BOUND**.

The lowest **COST** you find (including **CMAX**) is your answer.  Total complexity is **O(N log N)**, dominated by the sort.  If the upper bound is guaranteed to be small, then you can use a counting sort for that and get **O(N+k)**

Comment: Had something very similar to this in mind, but did not come to work out all the details. Sounds plausible, though. After sorting, you just need some running sums and then a single pass over the list should be enough.